# Como resolver o problema de lógica desse bloco de código php?

Tags: php, funções

Nesse pedaço do código, eu pego o que a url está enviando e guardo os parâmetros em `variáveis` para posteriormente passá-los para dentro de uma `function`.

```
if(isset($_GET['funcao']) && $_GET['funcao'] == 'lereresponder'){
    if (!empty($_GET['tipo']) && 
        !empty($_GET['funcao']) &&
        $_GET['funcao'] == 'lereresponder'){

        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $tipo = $_GET['tipo'];

        lerresponder($id, $tipo);

    }
}
```

Nesse próximo código que é a `function` estou recebendo os parâmetros com a  intenção de construir uma `view` através de uma consulta ao banco de dados usando os parâmetros capturados.

```
function lerresponder($id, $tipo){

    global $pdo;

    echo $id . '<br>';
    echo $tipo . '<br>';

}
```

Bom, estou recebendo os paramentos do `if(isset($_GET['funcao']) ...` lá dentro da `function` para fazer a consulta no banco de dados.

**Pergunta 1:** A forma como estou passando estes paramentos para a ***function*** parece correta?

**Pergunta 2:** Como chamar esta função? Assim: `lereresponder($id, $tipo)`?

Juntando o código e o arquivo aonde chamo a `function`, repeti a instrução `lerresponder($id, $tipo);` 3 vezes e isso me incomodou.

**Pergunta 3:** A forma de se escrever esse código está correta?

Comment: Adiciona também a parte em que repetes a função 3 vezes.

Comment: Solucionei ... só colocar o **if(isset($_GET['funcao']) && ...** dentro da view em vez de colocar no mesmo arquivo da **function** pra depois ter que chamar a **function** novamente na view.

Comment: Só problema de lógica ... :)

Comment: você tem dois `if` aninhados que fazer a mesma verificação, mesmo um usando `isset()` e o outro `empty()`, use apenas o `if` de dentro